# Domain bound SMS Otp autofill not working in WKWebView (but does in Safari)

Tags: ios, safari, wkwebview

When using SMS with the domain bound format (https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=z0i801mg) the autofill gets correctly suggested in Safari, but it doesn't in a `WKWebView` (on iOS).

You can easily try this yourself by navigating to "https://icloud.com" and logging in with "didn't receive code" -> "send message to ...". In Safari you will get the SMS and it will suggest you to insert the code from messages. In a `WKWebView` you get the SMS and nothing happens.

The format Apple is using is (but also doesn't work without the weird `%...`):

```
Your Apple ID code is: 123456 Do not share it with anyone.
@icloud.com #123456 %apple.com
```

If you now ask someone to send you an sms with the following content it will correctly suggest the autofill: `Your Apple ID code is: 123456 Do not share it with anyone.`

Another weird difference is that with the Safari autofill it triggeres a paste in the html input, but in `WKWebView` it forcefully sets the value of the html input.

Why are those implementations so different? Is there any way of getting domain bound SMS otp working with `WKWebView`?